# Legacy rails app upgrade to 6.0.4 results in huge response slowdown

Tags: performance, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm working on upgrading our legacy rails app to 6.0.4 and we're experience an oddity with our healthcheck endpoints responding in 1-2 second real time responses (up from 20-30 MS currently) but our rails logs show a response of 2-3 MS. Local results of curling our healthcheck endpoint:

```
➜  git:(rails/upgrade-to-6) ✗ time curl app.local/health_check
{"version":"release-30-241-g9dc39fcc2f::20210617174031"}curl app.local/health_check  0.01s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 3.798 total
➜  git:(rails/upgrade-to-6) ✗ time curl app.local/health_check
{"version":"release-30-241-g9dc39fcc2f::20210617174031"}curl app.local/health_check  0.01s user 0.00s system 1% cpu 0.931 total
➜  git:(rails/upgrade-to-6) ✗ time curl app.local/health_check
{"version":"release-30-241-g9dc39fcc2f::20210617174031"}curl app.local/health_check  0.00s user 0.00s system 1% cpu 0.969 total
```

First request is slow due to development loading the code but subsequent requests are still around 1 second real time.

The rails logs of those requests:

```
Started GET "/health_check" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-07-27 14:43:49 -0400
Creating scope :closed. Overwriting existing method ServiceRequest.closed.
DEPRECATION WARNING: Controller-level `force_ssl` is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.1. Please enable `config.force_ssl` in your environment configuration to enable the ActionDispatch::SSL middleware to more fully enforce that your application communicate over HTTPS. If needed, you can use `config.ssl_options` to exempt matching endpoints from being redirected to HTTPS. (called from <class:ApplicationController> at /home/jimmy/Work/project/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6)
Processing by HealthCheckController#index as */*
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1562)


Started GET "/health_check" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-07-27 14:43:54 -0400
Processing by HealthCheckController#index as */*
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3649)


Started GET "/health_check" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-07-27 14:43:56 -0400
Processing by HealthCheckController#index as */*
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3649)
```

The controller in question is very bare bones as it serves as a health check for our load balancer

```
class HealthCheckController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    app_version = App::VERSION
    db_version = ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version
    render json: { version: "#{app_version}::#{db_version}" }
  end
end
```

Even replacing the `app_version` and `db_version` code blocks with hardcoded integers I'm still seeing the same level of slowness.

After running stackprof for a while with a middleware the results aren't anything crazy (at least that I can tell)

```
==================================
  Mode: cpu(1000)
  Samples: 1404 (0.99% miss rate)
  GC: 134 (9.54%)
==================================
     TOTAL    (pct)     SAMPLES    (pct)     FRAME
        99   (7.1%)          99   (7.1%)     (marking)
        73   (5.2%)          73   (5.2%)     ActiveModel::AttributeMethods#respond_to?
       108   (7.7%)          64   (4.6%)     Hash#deep_dup
       400  (28.5%)          60   (4.3%)     ActiveRecord::Base#perform_attribute_assignment
       869  (61.9%)          55   (3.9%)     ActiveRecord::Core#initialize
       152  (10.8%)          55   (3.9%)     ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Read#_read_attribute
        53   (3.8%)          53   (3.8%)     ActiveModel::AttributeSet#[]
        42   (3.0%)          42   (3.0%)     ActiveSupport::PerThreadRegistry#instance
        39   (2.8%)          39   (2.8%)     Grape::Router#compile!
        82   (5.8%)          37   (2.6%)     ActiveRecord::DynamicMatchers#respond_to_missing?
        36   (2.6%)          36   (2.6%)     ActiveModel::Attribute#initialize
        35   (2.5%)          35   (2.5%)     (sweeping)
       278  (19.8%)          35   (2.5%)     ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment#_assign_attributes
        33   (2.4%)          33   (2.4%)     ActiveModel::Attribute#initialize_dup
        29   (2.1%)          29   (2.1%)     ActiveRecord::Core#initialize_internals_callback
        52   (3.7%)          28   (2.0%)     ActionDispatch::Journey::GTG::Builder#transition_table
       240  (17.1%)          27   (1.9%)     ActiveModel::AttributeAssignment#_assign_attribute
       117   (8.3%)          27   (1.9%)     ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Write#_write_attribute
        27   (1.9%)          27   (1.9%)     ActiveRecord::DynamicMatchers::Method.pattern
        26   (1.9%)          26   (1.9%)     Hash#stringify_keys
        25   (1.8%)          25   (1.8%)     ActiveModel::Type::Value#assert_valid_value
        36   (2.6%)          24   (1.7%)     ActiveRecord::Core#init_internals
        24   (1.7%)          24   (1.7%)     ActiveModel::Type::String#cast_value
        40   (2.8%)          22   (1.6%)     ActiveRecord::Scoping::ScopeRegistry#value_for
        24   (1.7%)          18   (1.3%)     block (2 levels) in class_attribute
        45   (3.2%)          18   (1.3%)     ActiveRecord::DynamicMatchers::Method.match
        42   (3.0%)          18   (1.3%)     ActiveModel::Type::Value#cast
        16   (1.1%)          16   (1.1%)     ActiveRecord::ModelSchema::ClassMethods#schema_loaded?
        16   (1.1%)          16   (1.1%)     AttrEncrypted#encrypted_attributes
        59   (4.2%)          16   (1.1%)     ActiveModel::Attribute#value
```

One thing that i've noticed is our pre-prod environments with the rails 6.0.4 version are seeing a spike in CPU utilization compared to our non uprgaded environments.

Everything seems to function fine as far as normal usage of the application, it's just slow enough that our load balancer is removing app servers from the rotation.

We're using unicorn in production and local development, our procfile entry for unicorn:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

and the config file:

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 4)
timeout 60
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end

  if defined?($nats_client)
    $nats_client.close
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['adapter'] = 'postgis'
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

I'm wondering if anyone has seen anything similar or has any leads I should look into.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was just an issue with upgrading Flipper, we had a large dataset of users gated to a feature and when upgrading to version 0.21.0 they now memoize features on *all* requests which caused significant slow down.